pyspark docker image build failing on python installation
I am trying to build a base docker image for pyspark as outlined here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.3/running-on-kubernetes.html. When I run the command, I get the folowing error
28.84 error: externally-managed-environment
28.84
28.84 × This environment is externally managed
28.84 ╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
28.84     python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
28.84     install.
28.84
28.84     If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
28.84     create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
28.84     Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
28.84     sure you have python3-full installed.
28.84
28.84     If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
28.84     it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
28.84     virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
28.84
28.84     See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.
28.84
28.84 note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
28.84 hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
------
Dockerfile:27
--------------------
  26 |     RUN mkdir ${SPARK_HOME}/python
  27 | >>> RUN apt-get update && \
  28 | >>>     apt install -y python3 python3-pip && \
  29 | >>>     pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
  30 | >>>     # Removed the .cache to save space
  31 | >>>     rm -rf /root/.cache && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  32 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt install -y python3 python3-pip &&     pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools &&     rm -rf /root/.cache && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I see that there's a bug ticket logged for this issue as well: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-49068
Is there any way to work around this to build the image?
I tried building the base image first using
 ./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r <repo> -t my_spark-base build

Then, tried to pass the base image for the pyspark image, but it didn't work.
